# Theory of Pull before Push in a Push Day Workout

Tags: exercise-technique

I have heard the phrase that people should do pull before push in a workout. But if I'm doing a push day in my push-pull-leg workout routine. How does pull before push apply here since all the exercises I'm doing on a push day is all exercises that involves pushing (e.g., barbell bench press, dumbbell bench press, shoulder press, tricep pushdown...etc)? Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**How does the principle of scheduling pulling exercises before pushing exercises within a workout apply to a day where you only do pushing exercises? It doesn't.**

That said, I'd also be very confident that this principle of scheduling pulling exercises before pushing exercises is just something that someone made up with no justification whatsoever, and would comfortably dismiss it even when programming pushing and pulling exercises within the same workout.

Comment: It blew my mind when I realized how much of popular fitness information was just totally made up nonsense.